# Scroll Event Not Working: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, xmlhttprequest, deprecation-warning

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/eRiddle/e1tc8f6p/)

So I am pulling widgets from an API and trying to display them dynamically. In the JS file I've got a scroll event on `line 104` that detects when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the window. When it does, I want it to display the next 3 widgets I have stored in the `allWidgets` array.

Before the user scrolls I copy the first three widgets from the `allWidgets` array, store them in separate variables, and append them to the page. This is on `line 94`.

The first time I scroll to the bottom of the page, it will load in the next three widgets. But the next time I scroll to the bottom I get the error:

`[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check <URL>.`

Does anyone know how I can remedy this? Really frustrated, been trying to figure it out for days!

Edit: JS Fiddle won't keep my scss for some reason. If you want it, here ya go:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kulim+Park&display=swap');


$dark: #211b13;
$darker: darken($dark, 30%);
$light: lighten($dark, 10%);
$lighter: lighten($dark, 50%);
$accent: #d17c2c;
$light-accent: lighten($accent, 8%);

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  background: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

#content {
  background-image: url(../../Images/background-texture-3.png);
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-image: url(../../Images/Demographic_Image.png);
}

header h1 {
  color: rgb(193, 193, 193);
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 2em 0 0 .2em;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin: 1.5em 0 0 .2em;
  }
}

// Quick Facts
.quick-background {
  background: linear-gradient(.25turn, #99f0c0, transparent);
}

.quick-facts {
  font-family: 'Kulim Park', sans-serif;
  background: url('../../Images/quick-facts-icn.png');
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 40%;
  padding: .3em 0;
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 quickFactSlide;
}

@keyframes quickFactSlide {
  0% {
    max-width: 40%;
    // border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateX(-10%);
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 40%;
    // border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
  }
}


.quick-facts h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: .5em;
  font-style: italic;
}

.total-num {
  animation: 4s ease-in-out infinite totalNumColor;
}

@keyframes totalNumColor {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  50% {
    color: white;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}

.total,
.num {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.total p,
.num p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.num {
  font-weight: 900 !important;
}

.widget-total-p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/


.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    // margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

#navbarSupportedContent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-info {
  background-color: $dark;
  border: 3px solid $darker;
}

.btn-info:hover {
  background-color: $light;
  border: 3px solid $dark;
}
//
// .btn-info:focus {
//   background-color: $lighter;
//   border: none;
//   outline: none !important;
//   box-shadow: none;
// }

.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.show>.btn-info.dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: $lighter;
  border: $light;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background: $dark;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: $dark;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $light;
}

.home-li {
  position: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: .3em .5em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: $light;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.home-li:hover {
  background-color: $accent;
}

// .home-li:focus {
//   outline: none !important;
//   box-shadow: none !important;
//   background-color: $lighter;
// }

.product-title {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: .5em 3.5em .5em .5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $light;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    background: $light;
}

// #sidebar ul li a:focus {
//     background: $light;
//     outline: none;
//     box-shadow: none;
// }

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

#sidebar .widget-link {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: $dark;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: $light !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

#sidebar .CTAs {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#sidebar .btn-li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background-color: $accent;
  border: 2px solid $light-accent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 90%;
  transition: background-color .75s ease-in-out;
}

#sidebar .btn-li:hover {
  background-color: $light-accent;
}

#sidebar .website-link {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: background-color .75s ease-in-out;
}

#sidebar .website-link:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#sidebar .website-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

#sidebar .logo-li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#sidebar .logo-img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  width: calc(90% - 250px);
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
}

#content.active {
    width: 100%;
}

.city-state-btn,
.zipcode-btn,
.county-btn,
.time-zone-btn {
  padding-right: 1.5em;
}

.btn-group {
   margin-left: .5em;
}

.city-state-btn::after,
.zipcode-btn::after,
.county-btn::after,
.time-zone-btn::after {
  right: 10px;
}

.filter-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.filter-by {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

input {
  margin: 0 .5em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  width: 245px;
}

.btn-control {
  font-family: 'Kulim Park', sans-serif;
  font-size: .9rem;
  background-color: #8ee6b5;
  border: 2px solid darken(#8ee6b5, 10%);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: .3em .5em;
}

.search-placeholder {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.placeholder-img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.placeholder-txt {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #content.active {
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    WIDGETS
----------------------------------------------------- */

.widgets {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.trivia-widgets,
.in-the-works-widgets {
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "widget-1 widget-2"
      "widget-3 widget-4"
      "widget-5 widget-6";
  }
  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "widget-1 widget-2 widget-3"
      "widget-4 widget-5 widget-6"
  }
}

.widget {
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

.widget-image {
  text-align: center;
}


iframe {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
}

body {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.weather-iframe,
.puzzle-iframe,
.in-the-works-iframe,
.games-iframe {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.details {
  margin: 0 .5em;
  background-color: rgb(242, 240, 227);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.details {
  padding: .5em 0 1em 0;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

.detail {
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
}

.span-detail {
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: italic;
}

.footer-div {
  z-index: 2000;
}

footer {
  // margin: 0 auto;
  height: 20px;
  // max-width: 90%;
  background-color: $dark;
}
```

Comment: The *warning* is caused in `weather.min.js`. Is that a file of yours?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you are the author of the widget are you able to change anything.
The https://w1.predictinteractive.com/widgets/weather/index.html page you get your widget from includes a JS file called `weather.min.js`. This file probably contains a *synchronous* `XMLHTTPRequest` which will block your thread, as the warning suggests.

You are probably better off using a more up to date widget which does not use synchronous `XMLHTTPRequest`s to get it's data. Or if you feel up to it use one of the many open weather API's and build your own widget.

**TL;DR** No way to fix it unless you can change the JS of the widget.

Comment: The api is from this link: https://weather.predictinteractive.com/weather/catalog

Comment: The weather.min.js is my file, yes. I've gotten this to work, but only by using `.shift()` on each widget from the `allWidgets` array. I don't want to mutate the original array, which is why I'm now using indices

Comment: I don't understand what `.shift()` has to do with it. Your problem lies in the improper usage of an `XMLHTTPRequest` not the `allWidgets` array.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I use .shift() to remove the next widget from the array, I can post the next three widgets no problem. But when the array is left unmutated, I get a depreciation error. Is this because it is inside an event listener?